# Connecting NodeSockets of differing types

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, node-editor

If you check the docs, you can see under `NodeSocket(bpy_struct)`:

> type Data type Is
>
> Type: enum in [‘CUSTOM’, ‘VALUE’, ‘INT’, ‘BOOLEAN’, ‘VECTOR’,
>   ‘STRING’, ‘RGBA’, ‘SHADER’], default ‘VALUE’

What happens, if you connect sockets of differing types? In particular, RGBA connected to SHADER (Mix -> Material Output), and RGBA connected to VALUE (Image Texture -> ColorRamp)? Can someone tell how blender converts between the differing types?

Comment: What are you asking about? These are simply types of sockets (the little dots on the sides of nodes), where usually you'll make connections between the same types (color > color, value > value...).

Comment: I'm asking because I find it weird, that I can connect RGBA socket to SHADER socket. Why? They are of different type.

Comment: blender assumes that you know enough to follow the color code at least

Comment: You can connect any socket type to any other socket type and usually the conversion is done automatically - the exception is the SHADER type, where only a shader socket plugged into another shader socket will work (although there's nothing physically stopping you from trying)

Comment: @GregZaal Can you enumerate how the conversions take place, i.e. how RGBA is converted to VALUE, for example. There are many possibilities, such as a weighted sum, taking only one of 4 values, etc... I'm also interested where in blender's code I could look up these conversions taking place. Also, you forget that I have RGBA plugged into the SHADER socket. It works, try it, though how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### RGB(A) to Value

It is neither a weighted sum nor the max channel (as is the case for Value in HSV) - instead it's something I don't understand at all, something to do with the black magic of color management, but I'm happy to write it here anyway :)

In `node_shader_valToTgb.c` is the function `node_shader_exec_rgbtobw`, which calls `IMB_colormanagement_get_luminance(col)`. Inside that function, we have `dot_v3v3(luma_coefficients, rgb)` - the dot product of the input color and some apparently random numbers at the top of that file: `luma_coefficients[3] = { 0.2126f, 0.7152f, 0.0722f };`

Recreating that as a node setup in blender gives the same result as you'd get from plugging the color into a Color Ramp node or RGB to BW node:

[image: rgb-v]

The cube render is black meaning the difference = 0

Shader nodes are always only RGB and never include an alpha channel. However, in the compositor they do. When converting RGBA to a Value in the compositor, the alpha channel is simply ignored - only the RGB values are used.

---

### RGB(A) to Vector

The alpha channel is simply discarded - Red becomes X, Green becomes Y, Blue becomes Z.

We can prove this by plugging a render into a Vector Curves node, and plugging that into a Viewer node - notice that the background becomes black (as the RGB values in that space were all 0):

[image: rgb-vec]

---

### Vector to RGB(A)

It's simply the opposite of what's said above. X becomes Red, Y becomes Green, Z becomes Blue. The alpha is always assumed to be 1.0.

---

### Anything to Shader

This is the one exception - nothing is ever automatically converted to a shader, the result is always simply black, no matter what color or value you plug into it.

Personally I think this design is silly - if you plug a color straight into the material output (without going through any shaders first), you're expecting the result to be *shadeless*. But alas, this is not the case.

---

### Value to RGB(A)/Vector

This is pretty obvious I think, but just for completeness: Whatever the value is becomes the same for each channel/axis when converted to RGBA/Vector (though the alpha channel simply = 1)

---

Have I missed anything?

Comment: About those "random" numbers, see [Relative luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) and [Luminosity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function).

Comment: The RGBA->Value conversion IS a weighted sum. I am positive, that conversion to SHADER are possible, after all the socket Material Output is of type SHADER and you can connect a RGBA socket to it.

Comment: Are you saying you can connect an RGB socket to a shader socket and it renders something other than black? Need a screenshot to believe that...

Answer (score 1):

[node_socket_copy_default_value()](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/nodes/intern/node_socket.c$270) seems to be responsible for moving data between node sockets, but it doesn't go along with the real behavior so I may be wrong, and here is some links further invistigation :

[node related definitions](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/BKE_node.h;025a64611423debe329514d7fe7f110937753eff$83)
[node directory in source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/nodes/)