# Material shown in material mode but not render mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I have material which is attached to my object and it is seen normally when i am in object mode/mateiral

[image]

But when i go into render mode i get object without material:
[image]

As you can see also in material preview it is gray.

It is cycles render.

Comment: Node setup is incorrect, use MixRGB instead of Mix shader. Green and yellow sockets are incompatible

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a mix shader node to mix RGB (image or texture) information.

[image]

Use a Color>MixRGB node instead.

[image]

You shouldn't mix data types when connecting nodes. Green goes with green, yellow with yellow and so on.

read:

[What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)

and

[Cycles - (Shader) Nodes - inputs outputs - What are the exact data types?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types)

and

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/nodes/parts.html