# Red line from Shader node to Color Ramp

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine

[image]

I was following a tutorial in order to learn nodes for 2.8. When this line turned red and made the entire thing pink (missing textures). Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: The mix Shader node doesn't make sense there, hence the red line. 'Mix RGB' node might work for your case

Comment: All of the connections are wrong. Don't connect texture's color output(yellow) to a mix shader(green). Don't connect shader outputs (green) to inputs that expect images (yellow or gray). don't conect color outputs (yellolow) to surface inputs (green). Read [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types

Answer (score 5):

In the latest builds of Blender 2.8, the node editor has been enhanced to highlight some links in red to indicate that they are invalid connections. In this particular case, you're using a Mix Shader node to mix colors - you should instead be using a MixRGB node for this; the Mix Shader should only be used to connect to Green sockets.

In general, you should only connect 'like for like' - ie, green to green, grey to grey, yellow to yellow, etc. There are exceptions to this and Blender can automatically convert between some types - eg, connecting a Scalar (Grey) socket to a Color (Yellow) will automatically generate a greyscale color. Similary, connecting a Color (Yellow) to a Scalar (Grey) will average all the color channels together as `(r+g+b)/3` to use the result.

However, Green represents a *shader* output - which is more than just a surface color and cannot be automatically converted - so connecting one of those to another color is not valid. Previously Blender would allow this without warning and simply produce an invalid result, but the Node Editor has now been enhanced to warn of such invalid connections by highlighting the link in Red.

Answer (score 0):

On The Red Line Put The "Shader To RGB" Node (Eevee Exclusive)

Comment: Do note though that RGB has to be converted to shader after ColorRamp since the latter outputs color. It is much more logical to cut Mix shader from where it is and paste it into the place between ColorRamp and Material Output in this case