Mix shader is not working with an emission node
I want to be able to animate a change in material using a mix shader node and keyframing the factor. I am mixing a glass BSDF and an emissions node to create a screen.
I want to be able to lead an image into the emissions node, but also want to be able to alter the image, as it is going to be animated. I am trying to change the image using a mix shader node but this does not work. Neither image is showing up. It only works when leading them directly into the mix shader with the Glass BSDF.


The color of the sockets gives a hint. You try to plug something yellow into something green and then from green into yellow again... Yes, some socket types are interchangeable, but the red connection line notifies you that there is something wrong. The thing is, you can plug the color outputs of the Image Texture nodes into the Mix Shader node, because it can convert the colors into surface shading information. The problem is, this shading information cannot be converted back to simple color information by the Emission node which it needs for the color input.

Mix Shader node is for mixing shaders. Mix Color node is for mixing colors and images.

The clue is the red connecting noodle between the Mix Shader and Emission nodes which indicates an error! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146493/red-line-from-shader-node-to-color-ramp

The problem is not even mixing the colors in the Mix Shader node - it converts the colors to shading information. The problem is, the color input of the Emission node cannot use it.
