# Transparent BSDF not working

Tags: node-editor

Why is this not transparent? The translucent BSDF works but not the transparent BSDF.

I'm using Cycles as a render engine. I've had this work in the past but for some reason it doesn't want to work anymore.

[image: scvreenshot]

Comment: The logic for your nodes is not correct. You cannot mix images and shaders like that. The nodes are color coded: green inputs are for shader information, the yellow ones are for RGB info.  Read: [what is the meaning of the color of the nodes in the node editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor) and [shader nodes input and output data types](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're viewing this in "Look Dev" (also called "Material Preview") mode:

[image]

That uses the realtime Eevee shader, even if you've selected Cycles as your main rendering engine.  Click on the little sphere to the right of the selected one for "Rendered" view, and that will probably fix the problem.

You can use transparency in Eevee, too, but it requires an extra setting.  You'll need the following steps:

1. Temporarily switch your rendering engine to Eevee.
2. With the transparent object selected, click on its material tab and scroll down to "Settings".  You should see a "Blend mode" setting.  (This will only appear if you've switched your rendering engine to Eevee first.)
3. Change the "Blend mode" to "Alpha blend" (or "Alpha hash" or "Alpha clip" -- see the manual for details).
4. Now you can change your rendering engine back to Cycles.

The transparency should now work both in Look Dev ("Eevee") and Rendered ("Cycles").

Comment: thank you so much i really appreciate it

Comment: In my case the problem was with freestyle lines. They don't render behind transparent faces.