# Cannot get shadows working with shader graph nodes

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shadows

I have a custom shader that is basicly just rendering a object with vertex colors. I am trying to get shadows working by using LightPath node, but everything renders black when I apply that node. Using Eevee renderer.

[image]

Comment: Hint: the colors of the nodes in and output socket indicate the type of the connections. Connections mostly only make sense between sockets of the same color. At the very least you probably want an emission BSDF somewhere.

Comment: That node arrangement makes no sense at all. You cannot mix different kinds of data and expect them to work.  Read: [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor) and [shader node ahat are the exact data types](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types)

Comment: @cegaton multiplying scalar with vector is possible, so that should work.

Comment: Looks like light path node can be used only with shader nodes, otherwise it does not do anything, even with matching colored node connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get control of the shadows was to have a light with high intensity, and then a mesh with white albedo color. Then the node graph in the image shows how to filter the shadowed part out from the render. There's no light path node at all anymore.

[image]