# Texture rendering in Eevee but not in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I'm facing some issues to render texture in Cycles. It works very well on Eevee engine.

Here is the Eeeve rendering with textures (lines on hills)
[image: Eevee rendering, with texture]

When I go to Cycles, nothing is rendered.
[image: Cycles rendering, without the texture]

I'm an early beginner so I probably miss something...
Thanks

Comment: You are connecting a color output (yellow socket) to a shader input (green socket). Try putting a shader node between the color ramp and the mix shader.

Comment: I gave it a try, still working well in Eevee but not in Cycle https://imgur.com/29L2m5o

Thanks, I find something interesting doing this anyway

Comment: Read: [what is the meaninf of the color of the node sockets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [cycles shader node inputs data types](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types/102521#102521)

Answer (score 1):

Try saving all your image files then try it again.  I had a similar problem and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you UV-unwrapped the model?
And I would try to take that colour ramp out and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already unwrapped the model (I did the mapping with Eevee engine on). I also tried to remove the color ramp, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Hi. Please don't use answers to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

feed the color output of the colorramp into a new principled bsdf and use that in the mix shader. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "hacky" solution : my texture is a png with black lines and transparent background. I changed lines to white and now they are rendered in Cycles (and I can change there colors with a shader so...)

Answer (score 0):

I switched from using the texture coordinate node to using the UV map node and it worked. Don't know why but it did.[image: Using the texture cordinate uvs][image: using the uv coordinate node]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mesh is not a *Shadow Catcher*:

- [image: Shaodw Catcher?]