# Why objects reflected in the mirror are darker than original, as they were not receiving light

Tags: materials, shaders, light

The curtains are dark in the mirror image, as they were the original object but not receiving the light of a point lamp that i used nodes to define color and strength (blackbody and ies texture). The mirror shader i got from one answer here to "realistic mirror", but the result is the same when I use a simple glossy bdsf, GGX (or others), white (RGB=0.8,0.8,0.8), roughness=0.000.
The other problem is that the translucent light that comes from  the window is different too...using "realistic mirror" it is brighter, and the simple glossy it becomes green! (I'm using cycles, an HDRI map for world and a point lamp) [image: mirror shader][image: render with reflection problems]

Comment: For one you have shader output going through a color input of a glossy shader. What is in the node group? Your material is broken it seems, and you likely do not have enough have enough light in the scene.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a (diffuse?)BSDF shader plugged into a glossy shader, this is not allowed by blender. Instead, add a mix shader, plug them both into it, and then plug the output into the material output.

This is just an example:
[image: MixShader]

Comment: For more info on the meaning of the colors for the node sockets read:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem isn't the mirror material (since I still have a problem, with a simple glossy bdsf linked to material. But the curtains material, I got from some youtube tutorial, it has a light path node, wich controls the fac of a mix shader. When i cut the link between add node and the fac mix shader the mirror works fine.
I dont have enough light in the scene because i didnt included all the lamps i'll need...i had this problem first. The mirror base color is pure...at least when i use the simple glossy shader.

Thanks for the answers!!!
[image: curtains material nodes]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the base color of your reflective material isn't pure white? Because that influences the appearance. A red mirror for example would also tint its reflection so a greyish mirror essentially just darkens the reflections.