# Is there a guide to learn more about nodes?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'm interested in nodes, but my understanding of them is lacking. I don't really know what most nodes do or what the connections mean (the yellow, grey and blue dots)

Comment: read here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor

Comment: Hello :). I can wholeheartedly recommend the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/shader_nodes/index.html)

Comment: @JachymMichal are you really asking folks to **read**? Is there a tutorial on how to do such a feat?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i think that should be closed as  Duplicate of [what is the meaning of the node sockets in the node editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor) and [Shader nodes what are the data types](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types)

Comment: @LoserLemur there are many different kind of nodes, namely for materials, compositing and for dealing with parametric geometry. Your question could be more specific in order to get a proper answer on this site. Otherwise it is too  big a topic. Please take the [tour] to understand how to get better answers on this site.

Comment: Try here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQ0qtcSymDI