# Mix shader not connecting ColorRamp and Transparent BSDF together in 2.9

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'm following a lesson of what I think was made in ver. 2.8 and I'm currently using 2.9.
As you can see in the image below (mine | lesson), in the lesson part the ColorRamp and Transparent BSDF are connected in the same shader socket in the Mix Shader and mine is not connecting both, when I try it just disconnect the other...
Is there any node I can add to make it work?

[image]

Comment: The ColorRamp in the tutorial image is connected to the Mix Factor (fac), not one of the input sockets. You can tell because it replaces the Value slider. Just a bad angle on the connection makes it look like it's connected elsewhere. Connect your ColorRamp to the grey dot and you're good to go.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I'm still learning and afraid of messing with anything I don't know, but also and my eyes are not that good and haven't noticed that hahah thank you so much!

Comment: Don't be afraid, that's what the undo button is for!

Comment: you should read [what is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor) and [cycles shader nodes what are the exact data types](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types?noredirect=1&lq=1)